# Populating User.Identity in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, signalr

I'm writing a simple chat application using ASP.NET MVC 5 and SignalR. The application doesn't require any complicated authentication logic. User simply enters their login and enters the system (if there was no such user in the db before, it's created).

My intent was to use Session to hold the logged in user and their information (id from the database and login/username) and write a global filter to check if user is authenticated on each request. I've got some problems with SignalR though. It's not possible to access the Session from the SignalR Hub, while I need it to find out the login of the user who sent the message.

As fas as I found out, it's possible to work with the User.Identity using SignalR's Context. However, in my case Uder.Identity is completely empty. Presumably because I've created the app as 'no authentication' and the mechanism that User.Identity uses to get user data is not aware of my manipulation with session.

The question is, is it possible to elegantly intergate User.Identity into my application and make it aware of the Session? Creating ASP.NET MVC project with individual user accounts creates a mess with stuff like

```
public AccountController() :
this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
{

}
```

and that's what I don't want to have in my application by any means, since I want to write it as clean as possible and not use any solutions I am not familiar with. I also don't need any external login providers, cookies, etc.

I was thinking about implementing some in-memory storage on my own. However, I would still have to clean this store up at some point of time. I though of cleaning it up when the Session_End event is fired. However, this event will only be fired if there is data in Session which I don't want to have since it would be quite awkward to have standalone in-memory storage and rely on Session events to clean it up and, moreover, to set some data in Session just to make sure Session_End will fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. It's still not as clear as I would like it to be and it uses cookies, so any additions are welcome.

First of all, I had to install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin package and all its dependencies.

Then I registered my auth as follows:

```
        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
```

This method is then called in Configuration method of Startup.cs file.

In order to work with the authentication, an instance of IAuthenticationManager is required. I inject it into my controller and use Ninject to resolve the dependency

```
 kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(_ => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InRequestScope();
```

Here's the Login method of Account controller which user is redirected to when auth is required (thanks to LoginPath in ConfigureAuth method):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = authenticationService.AuthenticateUser(model.Login);
        IdentitySignIn(user.Id, user.Login);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

AuthenticationService is my own class which communicates with the database and performs the login to create or return a user.

IdentitySignIn is declared as follows:

```
        private void IdentitySignIn(int userId, string userLogin)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, userId.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userLogin));

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(200),
                    IsPersistent = true
                }, identity);
        }
```

This method creates a cookie with appropriate info. There is one thing, though. When I check the cookie expiration date, it's not the current date plus 200 days, which is kinda awkward.

SignOut method is quite simple:

```
        public void IdentitySignout()
        {
            authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        }
```

So, User.Identity is now accessible in the SignalR hub with the Identity.Name property.

To do: it would be also nice to get access to the Id property via something like User.Identity.Id. As far as I know, it requires implementing custom Principal. 
I am also still thinking of implementing some sort of session of my own using cookies to store the session id on client side, though it will definitely take more time than using Identity.

**Addition:** 
in order to get user id, one might use the extension method of IdentityExtensions:

(Inside the Hub)

```
Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

In order for this to work, the Claim with the value of user's id should have the type ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier.

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>();
 claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId.ToString()));
 claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userLogin));
```

Update 2:

Here are some additional links on the subject that greatly helped me. I do not include links to MS guides since they are quite easy to find.

http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/21/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-claims-authentication/

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application